# Code Coverage issue when spyon is used

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am writing a `unit test` for my `component`(Angular2 app) using `Karma-Jasmine`. And I am making use of `Istanbul` for Code Coverage report.

Here is my test case,

```
it('Should Invoke onNext function', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const login = fixture.componentInstance;

    spyOn(login, 'onNext');

    let email = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("input[name='username']");
    email.value = "email";

    let nextButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button")[1];
    nextButton.click();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(login.onNext).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  }));
```

As you can see I am `spying on onNext function` to verify whether it is getting called or not on `nextbutton click`. It is working fine and the test passes.

But the code coverage report for my Login page shows that the onNext function is  not covered.
[image]

**What am I doing wrong??**

And also if I don't spy on onNext function, the function is covered,

```
it('Should Invoke onNext function', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const login = fixture.componentInstance;


    let email = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("input[name='username']");
    email.value = "email";

    let nextButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button")[1];
    nextButton.click();
  }));
```

[image]

Comment: Because the spy actually replaces the function call. You have to make two tests : the first will test if the function is actually called (what you did), and the second will test your onNext function.

Comment: Didn't know that..Thanks for the info. Is there a better way to do that? such that I can achieve both at the same time?

Comment: Yeah, put them both in the same `it` (although I wouldn't recommend that). By the way, calling `component.onNext()` will cover it in the code coverage, but it's not testing ! Testing means you have to use assertions to test if whether or not you get the correct values

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this:

`spyOn(login, 'onNext').and.callThrough()`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.. Thanks